# send POST action from controller, follow action

Tags: php, symfony, post

Is it possible to send a form submission from a controller, but follow the action in the browser?

I know you cant redirect post, but is there a way to send the submission in the controller and it continues like a normal POST?

e.g.

```
function paymentHandler(){
     // validation data
     // save data
     redirect/send POST with data to paymentgatewy which is external
    // gateway page should be what the user then sees
}
```

Comment: That is where curl comes in: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php There are also some libraries/bundles wrapping curl to make using it a bit easier.  I like guzzle: http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by doing form submission with javascript. Just render your page with form that is filled with needed data and post it to the payment gateway by JavaScript.